# Error creating procedure and seting a variable to a query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

this is s straight forward question but i can't find the error

```
CREATE PROCEDURE agregarCitaNota(in id int, in nota text)
BEGIN
DECLARE @column text;
SET @column = (SELECT Detalle FROM cita WHERE idCita = id);
IF @column = null THEN
    UPDATE cita SET Detalle = nota WHERE idCita = id;
ELSE
    UPDATE cita SET Detalle = Detalle + nota WHERE idCita = id;
END$
```

For some reason, it's giving me an error, i've been working on this code and it's not working. It says that it's in the line where

```
Set @column = (Select Detalle FROM cita WHERE idCita = id);
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@column text; SET @column = (SELECT Detalle FROM cita WHERE idCita = id); IF @' at line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `@`. There's a difference between [user defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html) (@) and declared variables (no @).

Also you shouldn't name variables like keywords.

Comparisons with `null` are done with `... is null`, not `... = null`.

If you just want to know, if an entry exists, use `exists()` rather than actually getting the data.

If you want to append text to text, use `concat()`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE agregarCitaNota(in id int, in nota text)
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Detalle FROM cita WHERE idCita = id) THEN
    UPDATE cita SET Detalle = nota WHERE idCita = id;
ELSE
    UPDATE cita SET Detalle = CONCAT(Detalle, nota) WHERE idCita = id;
END IF;
END$
```

Comment: Thanks man, it didn't gave me the error now, but it's not concatenating, it always overwrites the value. It's animprovement over my code haha, but it still not doing it, also i was missing an end if; but it still not concatenating.

Comment: I FIXED IT! I just needed to ad a NOT to IF NOT EXISTS. Thanks man!